# Reverse Engineering - Find Missing Values

Tags: variables, actionscript, reverse-engineering

In the following function, I need to find the values for "a" and "b" or "a" and "toliau".

Maybe it's because it's early, but I can't figure this out.

Currenty I have solved for the following, but it appears to be incorrect:

```
a = vrt 
vrt = 'LBLUVTBXQ'
b= "xxx9xx8" or b= "xxx8xx9"
```

**Code:**

```as
a = _root.user;
b = _root.pass;
main = "ABCDEFGHIYJKLMNOPRSTUVZXQW0123456789";

vrt = ((((((((substring(main, 12, 1)) + (substring(main, 1, 1))) + (substring(main, 12, 1))) + (substring(main, 15, 0))) + (substring(main, 20, 1)))
    + (substring(main, 21, 1))) + (substring(main, 19, 1))) + (substring(main, 1, 1))) + (substring(main, 23, 2));

toliau = ((substring(_root.main, 18, 2)) + (substring(b, 3, 1))) + (substring(b, 6, 1));

if ((a == vrt) && (((substring(b, 3, 1)) * (substring(b, 6, 1))) == 72))
   geturl("level8-" + toliau + ".htm", "_self");
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not very clear at all.

Comment: Trying to find the username and password. It was intentionally made to be unclear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username is KAKTUSAZX. I know this because I know you're trying to solve the level 7 question in try2hack.lt like me. :D happy hacking

ps I used Macromedia Flash MX to figure out the username. no need to actually work out stuff

Comment: Haha thanks for the answer. I ended up figuring this out too.